# Disposing HttpResponseMessage and its Content when throwing HttpResponseException inside action method

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, idisposable

The source of my question is the following code, which is part of a code snippet contained in the [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/error-handling/exception-handling#httpresponserexception) for exception handling in asp.net web api:

```
var resp = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.NotFound)
{
    Content = new StringContent(string.Format("No product with ID = {0}", id)),
    ReasonPhrase = "Product ID Not Found"
};
throw new HttpResponseException(resp);
```

Both `HttpResponseMessage` and `StringContent` implement `IDisposable` interface, but no one in the above code calls method `IDisposable.Dispose`.
Is this a problem ? Is there any side effect involved in not disposing those objects ?

According to [this article](https://www.strathweb.com/2015/08/disposing-resources-at-the-end-of-web-api-request/) a possible solution could be changing the above code to the following:

```
var content = new StringContent(string.Format("No product with ID = {0}", id));
var resp = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.NotFound)
{
    Content = content,
    ReasonPhrase = "Product ID Not Found"
};

this.Request.RegisterForDispose(content);
this.Request.RegisterForDispose(resp);

throw new HttpResponseException(resp);
```

Is this really necessary, or is it possible to avoid this (according to what is showed in the Microsoft documentation)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Response wrapped by `HttpResponseException` will be disposed by asp.net framework, like any other response you return from your action. You can easily test that yourself by creating dummy response message:

```
class DummyResponse : HttpResponseMessage {
    public DummyResponse(HttpStatusCode statusCode) : base(statusCode) {
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing) {
        Console.WriteLine("dispose called");
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
}
```

Then throw `HttpResponseException` with that response and put breakpoint in `Dispose` override. You will observe that `Dispose` is called, and if you look at call stack, you will see that `HttpControllerHandler` is responsible for doing that (in asp.net web api controller).

Note that this exception is caught by `ApiControllerActionInvoker`, class that is responsible to invoke your api controller actions. It then just grabs `yourException.Response` and pushes it forward through the pipeline, so throwing this exception is no different from just returning corresponding response from your api controller action. It should be clear I think that framework will dispose all those responses when its done with them. It would be pretty poor design otherwise.

So, don't clutter your code with those `RegisterForDispose` and let framework handle this for you.

Answer (score 4):

Checking the [Microsoft Source for HttpResponseMessage.CS](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Net.Http/src/System/Net/Http/HttpResponseMessage.cs):

```
protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
{
    // The reason for this type to implement IDisposable is that it contains instances of 
    // types that implement IDisposable (content). 
    if (disposing && !_disposed)
    {
        _disposed = true;
        if (_content != null)
        {
            _content.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

`content` is of type HttpContent.  Checking the [Microsoft Source for HttpContent.cs](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Net.Http/src/System/Net/Http/HttpContent.cs):

```
protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
{
    Debug.Assert(_buffer != null);

    ArrayPool<byte>.Shared.Return(_buffer);
    _buffer = null;

    base.Dispose(disposing);
}
```

The comments for [ArrayPool](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Buffers/src/System/Buffers/ArrayPool.cs) say:

```
/// Renting and returning buffers with an <see cref="ArrayPool{T}"/> can increase performance
/// in situations where arrays are created and destroyed frequently, resulting in significant
/// memory pressure on the garbage collector.
```

Examining the source for ArrayPool yields this lovely gem:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Retrieves a shared <see cref="ArrayPool{T}"/> instance.
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>
    /// The shared pool provides a default implementation of <see cref="ArrayPool{T}"/>
    /// that's intended for general applicability.  It maintains arrays of multiple sizes, and 
    /// may hand back a larger array than was actually requested, but will never hand back a smaller 
    /// array than was requested. Renting a buffer from it with <see cref="Rent"/> will result in an 
    /// existing buffer being taken from the pool if an appropriate buffer is available or in a new 
    /// buffer being allocated if one is not available.
    /// </remarks>
    public static ArrayPool<T> Shared
    {
        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
        get { return Volatile.Read(ref s_sharedInstance) ?? EnsureSharedCreated(); }
    }
```

`ArrayPool` doesn't use `WeakReference`s or any similar mechanism to insure proper disposal.  If you rent a buffer from `ArrayPool.Shared`, you have to return it, or you will cause a memory leak.

So yeah, I'd say respecting `IDisposable` is pretty important here.

Comment: But OP talks about asp.net web api (so, full .NET) and you point to sources of .net core (which as I remember does not even have this exception). Not to mention whatever handles this exception (it's special one after all) might also dispose response wrapped by it.

Comment: @Evk: It's highly likely that the full .NET source is very similar, if not identical.  It wouldn't be that hard to check.

Comment: I doubt, given that HttpResponseException does not exist in. Net core, and ArrayPool is not used in asp.net mvc (not core), it did not exist back then.

Comment: @Evk: You're right.  I went and looked at the source for the .NET Framework System.Web.Http dll using JustDecompile, and there's no ArrayPool there.  There are a couple of Streams that get disposed, but it's hard to tell whether or not letting them garbage-collect naturally would have any negative repercussions.

Comment: @Evk at a first sight I didn't notice that the source code you linked above is related to .NET core. I don't know how asp.net web api handles an exception of type HttpResponseException, for sure there is something built in to handle this kind of exception because the response received on client side is what you expect both for status code and for the content. Maybe the resources we are talking about are transparently disposed by the framework at a proper time ?